# Web Scraping: Select drop down issue

Tags: scrape

trying to scrape the data for these races

http://form.greyhounds.betfair.com/racingform

I want to grab each race and each time so i need to methodically work through the two drop down fields which load each race but im not sure how to automate the process?!

Answer (score 0):

Which tool are you using? Selenium has ways to click on a dropdown and select a particular option. You can write a program to do it repeatedly for different options in the dropdown.